# Running torch on docker with CUDA says module 'cutorch' not found

Tags: docker, machine-learning, torch

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. I have a docker container running deep neural networks perfectly. But if I specify to use cuda, it throws the following errors:

```
/root/torch/install/bin/luajit: /root/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:384: module 'cutorch' not found:No LuaRocks module found for cutorch
    no field package.preload['cutorch']
    no file '/root/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/cutorch.lua'
    no file '/root/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/cutorch/init.lua'
    no file '/root/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/cutorch.lua'
    no file '/root/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/cutorch/init.lua'
    no file './cutorch.lua'
    no file '/root/torch/install/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta1/cutorch.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/cutorch.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/cutorch/init.lua'
    no file '/root/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/cutorch.so'
    no file '/root/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/cutorch.so'
    no file '/root/torch/install/lib/cutorch.so'
    no file './cutorch.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/cutorch.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /root/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:384: in function 'require'
    /root/openface/batch-represent/main.lua:22: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    /root/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:145: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00406670
```

Should CUDA/nvidia drivers be installed over the docker container separately ? if yes, then how ?

I am using a GTX Geforce TITAN black.

Comment: have you tried `luarocks install cutorch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I was using a docker file which was only meant to be used for executions over CPU.

I should create a another docker file or use something like [Dl-docker](https://github.com/floydhub/dl-docker) or [Nvidia-docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker).